# Running programs on Ubuntu with different environment

Tags: desktop-environments, debian

I was wondering if programs will run same as normal if I change DE from Unity (I guess that is the default for Ubuntu) to Deepin 15.10.

My main struggle is that I use software for chemistry (Chemaxon) that I know works on Ubuntu (should work on all Debian-based systems) and also a program written by a guy from my research group.

I believe the core of Ubuntu doesn't change at all and only the face of it does, right? The system will still be based on Ubuntu underneath? So I might get some issues with gui of some programs but everything that runs on my Ubuntu 19.04 now should still run after the switch?

Comment: Deepin is based on Debian (not Ubuntu). While that makes it a cousin to Ubuntu, we don't keep track of the changes that the Deepin developers make, and we don't provide support for it. Cousins might be alike, or might be very different.

Comment: @user535733 That seems like an answer to me. Would you post it below? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes all programs should work fine no matter which Window Manger you choose.